# "Улов не улов, а обрыбиться надо" - значение пословицы

Tags: этимология, лексика, выбор-слов, история

*Отважен уж очень. У него валяй, не гляди, что будет впереди, - **улов не улов, а обрыбиться надо.***
[**П.И.Мельников-Печерский, На горах**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=krVqCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA232&lpg=PA232&dq=%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=mKg7XKfl6o&sig=giWG4bSrbHShOwDzh5o_PD3S-G4&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOkJyj_drTAhUlIpoKHSMjC8wQ6AEITTAI#v=onepage&q=%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE&f=false)

*– Но как же ты ей пришлешь письмо? – спросил он его.

Сенька ответил:

– Не век тут будем сидеть; **улов не улов, а обрыбиться надо!** – и спрятал письмо за голенище.*
[**Г.Данилевский, Княжна Тараканова**](http://iknigi.net/avtor-grigoriy-danilevskiy/23288-knyazhna-tarakanova-sbornik-grigoriy-danilevskiy/read/page-35.html)

В.И. Даль. Пословицы русского народа. 
*Улов не улов, а обрыбиться надо* (уральск. казач.). 
**См.** СМЕЛОСТЬ - ОТВАГА - ТРУСОСТЬ.

Посмотрела, - значения пословицы не нашла. И при чём тут рыба? Подскажите.
 Мне кажется, что сейчас глагол "обрыбиться" приобрел совсем другое значение.

Comment: Не тянет на пословицу.

Comment: мне кажется, эта пословица близка к выражению "Была не была!"

Answer (score 2):

Улов не улов, а обрыбиться надо (уральск. казач.).

Эта пословица на тему "Что робеть, то хуже", **призыв к смелым действиям для получения желаемого результата (надо попробовать, а вдруг повезет).**  Также: Крут бережок, да рыбка хороша. ... Господь не выдаст, и враг (свинья) не съест. Валяй, не гляди, что будет впереди.

**А вообще говоря, глагол "обрыбиться" очень интересный, имеет разные значения, кроме словарного:**

1. Поймав первую рыбу, положить начало улову.
2. Наловить (много) рыбы.
3. Преуспеть в чем-либо, или, наоборот, не преуспеть (второе, кажется, чаще).

Примеры: http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=103213

Около нее не обрыбишься, — не обращая внимания на угрозу, поясняет Чижик.

Он хотел посмотреть время и обрыбился: часы остались на тумбочке.

Антон порезал омуля, освободил от косточек. Я взял кусочек, обрадовался, что воронёнок распялил рот, ан и тут мы обрыбились: не ест — и всё.

- Ну, ладно, гони чупу.
- Обрыбишься, за ней еще в магазин сходить надо, – выкрикнула Маня.

Answer (score 1):

"Улов не улов, а обрыбиться надо." Даль приводит эту пословицу (Даль В. Пословицы русского народа) в разделе СМЕЛОСТЬ - ОТВАГА - ТРУСОСТЬ рядом с другой пословицей: "Крут бережок, да рыбка хороша." Обрыбить, по Далю, -  дать случай поймать рыбу, обрыбиться - поймать первую рыбу. Исходя из этого, пословицу можно понимать так: будет ли улов неизвестно, но начинать ловить рыбу надо. Это напоминает мне слова Наполеона "Нужно сперва ввязаться в бой, а там видно будет" ([Викицитатник](https://ru.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD_I_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82))

Comment: Простите, но Ваш "Викицитатник" пуст.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Спасибо, я обновил ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

"Обрыбиться" у рыбаков означает "поймать первую рыбку". Это значение и сейчас существует – спросите у заядлых рыбаков. То есть – ещё не улов, но уже с рыбой.

Comment: У рыбаков-то всё понятно. Почему же Даль "относит" поговорку в раздел "смелость-отвага-трусость", а не в раздел, связанный с трудом, профессией?